# IDE when import scipy, ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, importerror

When I use pycharm to run my code with `from scipy import stats`:

> Importerror occurs: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

**Platform:** Anaconda, python 3.7

**IDE:** pycharm, Microsoft VS code
Anaconda is installed in D:\Anaconda

The `scipy` package is installed properly. The code can be run successfully in `Jupyter`.

I have tried the similar questions, but no one can help. Can anybody give me some help to fix it?

I have also reinstalled Anaconda, however, it still faied.

From scipy import stats:

> Traceback (most recent call last): ...from scipy import stats   File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats__init__.py", line 345, in
>   
>       from .stats import *   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 171, in
>   
>       from . import distributions   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py", line
>   10, in 
>       from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,   File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_distn_infrastructure.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from scipy import optimize   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize__init__.py", line 271,
>   in 
>       from ._minimize import *   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minimize.py", line 21,
>   in 
>       from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg__init__.py", line
>   117, in 
>       from .eigen import *   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen__init__.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from .arpack import *   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack__init__.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from .arpack import *   File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py",
>   line 45, in 
>       from . import _arpack ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMHfO.png)

I solved it!
I think there must be something wrong in Scipy packages in Conda, so I remove all the packages related to Ski-learn, and download from "https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy".

Choose numpy+whl Scipy ski-learn(corresponding edition) after downloading and install it by pip.